# How to install vue.js version 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to install version 2 of vue.js to use vuetify. However, I don't know the command for that. Could someone pass the command to me please

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html

Comment: There is no code to show how to install a specific version of vue.js

Comment: (  npm i vue@2.6.12  )  you can add other version that you want after @

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for a specific version of Vue2 you can run the following command with npm: `npm install vue@2.x.x` or if you want the latest, simply `npm install vue`.

For vue3 it is: `npm install vue@next`

Answer (score 3):

Сreated a new Vue.js project using Vue CLI. Select during installation Vue2

```html
vue create my-app
# navigate to new project directory
cd my-app
```

Add vuetify

```js
vue add vuetify
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install vue@2.x.x --save
```

It will update package.json as well.
so later on, if you need to install the project from git, by running
`npm install`
easily package can be installed

Comment: "npm run build" was failing with error "Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'styles' of undefined". You pointed me to the solution: remove Vue CLI and let 'npm install' do its thing. Everything ok now.