# How to install older version of vue 2.6.11?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

*I want to install vue 2.6.11 which command line would work for that ?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install vue.js version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564955/how-to-install-vue-js-version-2)

Comment: hi thanks. it works but it works only in the particular folder not globally. Is there a way to install it globally ?

Comment: Hi, just add the -g flag at the command `npm install -g vue@2.6.11`
. More here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install#description

Comment: not sure why it is not working because on npm list vue it shows and empty list. and vue --version shows the cli version not the vue version. I'm confused

Comment: I think because installing Vue (not Vue CLI) globally makes no sense. Why you want do that? "Vue" is the library that you add in your Vue projects. Vue CLI is the utility to create and manage Vue projects. Is it more clear?

Comment: I see thanks, yeah if I create a new vue app, it works. But I have cloned an existing repo and wanted to check the vue version of that application. It might be missing something. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
npm install vue-router@2
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is here: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564955/how-to-install-vue-js-version-2/66565208#66565208)

Simply write `npm i vue@2.6.11` in the terminal of the project folder.

You can navigate to that project folder using `cd` inside of any terminal.